# nativescript javascript webview loading bar or loading icon

Tags: javascript, webview, nativescript

I 'm new with nativescript ;
I have a webView in which a external website is loaded.
I need To display icon or bar while webview url is loading ;

My XML VIEW :

```
<Page class="page"
navigatingTo="pageLoaded"  
xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
actionBarHidden="true"
>

    <GridLayout  >

    <Image src="~/img/loading1.gif" width="75%" class="logo"  visibility="{{ showDetails? 'visible' :  'collapsed' }}" />

    <WebView id="webView" loaded="onWebViewLoaded" loadFinished="loadFinished" src="preload.html"   visibility="{{ showDetails? 'collapsed' :   'visible'}}" />
</GridLayout>
```

My Controller

```
    var webViewModule = require("ui/web-view");
var observable = require("data/observable");
var pageData = new observable.Observable();




function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;

    pageData.set("showDetails",true );
    args.object.bindingContext = pageData; 

    var web = page.getViewById("webView");     
    web.src = "http://icon-dz.com/sap/pw";

}
function loadFinished(args) {

    pageData.set("showDetails", false );
    args.object.bindingContext = pageData; 


}

function onWebViewLoaded(args) {

    pageData.set("showDetails", false);
    args.object.bindingContext = pageData; 


}
exports.onWebViewLoaded = onWebViewLoaded ;
exports.loadFinished  = loadFinished ; 
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Can you help me to understand how exactly is supposed to be working?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between loadFinished() and onWebViewLoaded() , they do same work in your JS‍♂️

You can use **Activity Indicator** and remove gif. You should fix logical mistakes like loadFinished<>onWebViewLoaded. 
There is an easy usage of Activity Indicator with Webview [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/web-view#events).

I think first you need to check some topics of docs like; *dataBinding* etc.